# Some rows giving "String or binary data would be truncated" error when editing in Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssms

When trying to add data to a newly created column using SQL Server Management Studio (edit rows), I am getting the following error:

> No row was updated.
>
> The data in row 1 was not committed.
>
> Error Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider.
>
> Error Message: String or
>   binary data would be truncated.
>
> The statement has been terminated.
>
> Correct the errors and retry or press
>   ESC to cancel the change(s).

The datatype for the column is nvarchar(150).

---

UPDATE:
I am inserting only a few ascii characters (example: abc).

This is someone else's database who asked me to look into it... I discovered:
a) only some of the rows give this error
b) the rows giving this error have long strings in two other columns (one is a nvarchar(max), and one is ntext).

Comment: Is there only a single column in that table?  What are the types and lengths of all the columns and what does your insert/update statement look like?

Comment: There are multiple columns, see my update above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've experienced this on occasions when a table had a mixture of `ntext` and `nvarchar(MAX)` datatypes. Changing all the `ntext`s to `nvarchar(MAX)`s fixes the problem.

Answer (score 3):

This error typically occurs when you exceed the length of the data type for the column.  Are you inserting more than 150 characters into the column?

Comment: I'm only inserting a few characters. I updated some new findings in the post.

Comment: Hmmm - It’s possible to ignore the 'String or binary data would be truncated' message by setting ANSI_WARNINGS to OFF. This will truncate fields where they don’t fit. ANSI_WARNINGS OFF has drawbacks and it is better to correct a problem rather than ignore it. Another thing to check is whether the table update is firing any triggers that insert or update another table.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I mistakenly exceeded the number of characters that a field could hold. In Visual Studio, I had mistakenly inserted a field with its datatype as **nvarchar(1)** and was trying to save a word with 6 characters to that field. Once I changed to **nvarchar(50)**,  it worked fine. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Whoever designed a table with a **nvarchar(1)** column lacked some very basic knowledge about databases.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this occurs when tried insert more symbols, what is given to this field.
go to `Design`, check the `Data Type` of field
for Example your `Data Type = nvarchar(20)` and your tried set the 30 characters

---

Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when trying to edit a row in a table that had even one field of type `text`.  It still seems to be an issue even in SSMS 18 (in 2021).